# My AWS EC2 VM is not receiving HTTP from an external browser to the elastic IP of my EC2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http, amazon-elastic-ip

**Problem**

Can't browse my web app on my new AWS EC2 VM.
Wireshark on VM, shows a little HTTP activity, but nothing when I browse my URL or its elastic IP from an external browser (at my home office).

**My Setup**

My ASP.NET Web app is running on my AWS EC2 virtual server with Windows Server 2016 64-bit.
I configured IIS.
I set up an Elastic IP, which shows up in my AWS console instance.
I did nothing special with firewall

**Background**

My web app has worked ok on AZURE for years, and now I want to move it to AWS.

Comment: Have you created a security group rule that will allow that kind of traffic to the instance?

Comment: Also, posting your configurations would help to identify problems. I can at best guess given the data provided.

Comment: No I have not.  I will now investigate. (lots of online doc on how to)

Comment: That worked!  But now I get:  403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: This is a misconfiguration on your side. Errors 4xx are server-side errors.

Comment: What could the misconfig be?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the detailed error message from the error logs, as well as relevant configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spooler's hypothesis was correct.

Solution is to update security group, and that fixes it.

Comment: @DaveM There isn't any other answer on this question. This answer is referring to a comment, not another answer. That said, this answer does need some editing to meet the standards of this site. Answers need to be useful on their own without relying on comments or outside references. It's still perfectly fine to cite comments and outside references were appropriate, but it's no substitute for writing an answer that's useful even without those references.